# Deluxe table which extends to next page

Tags: longtable, deluxetable

I am trying to create a `deluxetable` that is also a long table (extends to next page). I have a large number of rows, close to  60-70 ones, and I want them to be in two pages. However, when I put all the data in the table, after the first page, some data seem missing. I want data to be distributed in the long table which is also a `deluxetable`. Especially I don't want two separate tables with different numbers, but one long table and written as 'continued table 1' in the second one. Could someone please help me?
Thanks in return.

```tex
\documentclass[twocolumn,linenumbers]{aastex631}
\begin{document}

\begin{deluxetable*}{ccccccccccc}[ht!]
\tabletypesize{\scriptsize}
\tablewidth{700pt}
\tablecaption{test }
\tablehead{\colhead{a} & \colhead{b}& \colhead{c} & \colhead{d} &\colhead{e}&\colhead{f}&\colhead{g}
&\colhead{h}&\colhead{i}&\colhead{j}&\colhead{k}\\
} 
\colnumbers
\startdata
1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1\\
\enddata
\tablecomments{test}
\end{deluxetable*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The [AASTeX author guide](https://journals.aas.org/aastexguide/#table_cheat_sheet) mentions that you can extend a `deluxetable` across pages by adding `\startlongtable` before your `deluxetable` environment. Is this what you're looking for?